# Two chances tossing a fair coin

Tags: probability

what are the probability of getting a tail on a fair coin toss. But I have 2 chances. (What I mean is: if I toss 1st time and get tail, I win, if not I can try a second time.)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this question, we find the probability that we get NO tails, and subtract that from $1$.

The probability of getting no tails is the probability of getting two heads, which is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus, the probability of getting tails is

$$1-\frac{1}{4}=\boxed{\frac{3}{4}}.$$

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was thinking, It is not required to toss 2 times. If I get tail on the 1st attempt I will not toss again, only in the case I don't get it on the 1st toss.

Comment: I get what you mean. Using your way, we can get the same answer in a slightly different way: The probability we get tails the first time is $\frac{1}{2}$. The probability we get heads the first time and tails the second time is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. Thus, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\boxed{\frac{3}{4}}$; the same. Welcome to StackExchange, by the way!

Comment: @aamv: That's true, but it doesn't matter, because if both tosses are tails, then the second toss is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of getting tail P(A) = $\frac12$

Probability of getting not tail P(A') = $1 - \frac12$ = $\frac12$

So there are two chances in first case tail or in second case.

In first case,

P(A) = $\frac12$

In second case first head comes then tail,

P(A') * P(A) = $\frac12$ * $\frac12$ = $\frac14$

Total  probability = $\frac12$ + $\frac14$ = $\frac34$